# English meaning of risk vs odds?

Tags: odds-ratio

I am trying to learn more about the difference between risk vs odds (e.g. relative risk, odds ratio). Since English is not my first language, these words have identical meanings to me:

- Smokers have higher odds of developing cancer compared (relative) to non-smokers
- Smokers have a higher risk of developing cancer compared (relative) to non-smokers

While I understand that the formulas used to calculate Relative Risk ( a/b / c/d) is completely different from Odds Ratio (a/a+b / c/c+d) ... I can't seem to understand how to explain this difference.

Suppose in a certain experiment about smokers/non-smokers vs cancer/non-cancer , the relative risk is calculated as "x" and the odds ratio is calculated as "y". It means:

- Smokers are "x" times more likely to develop cancer than non-smokers?
- Having cancer when smoking vs cancer when not smoking is "y" times more likely than smoking and having cancer vs smoking and not having cancer?

Is this the correct way to say it in English?

Comment: They are expressing different things.  Here are three examples each with roughly the same odds ratio of about $4$:  (a) the probabilities of $0.4\%$ and $0.1\%$ (relative risk: $4$); (b) the probabilities of $99.9\%$ and $99.6\%$ (relative risk $1.003$); (c) the probabilities of $66.7\%$ and $33.3\%$ (relative risk $2$).    In some sense (b) is the complement of (a) while both of them involve much smaller probability differences than (c).  If you are going to talk about either "odds ratios" or "relative risks" then you need to ensure that your listeners understand what you are saying.